# Erro ao carregar arquivo com File Editor

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando fazer um editor de `html`, mas não estou conseguindo ler o arquivo no editor utilizando `JavaScript`.

```
 var loadFile = function(name) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(name, {}, function(fileEntry) {
          currentFile = fileEntry;
          fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
              updateVisualEditor(this.result);
            }
          }, fsError);
        }, fsError);
      };
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar detalhes do erro.

Comment: Não aparece erro nenhum , só não o a nova aba abre em branco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o que falta é você ler o arquivo.

Introduza a seguinte linha no seu código e faça o teste.

> reader.readAsText(file);

```
 var loadFile = function(name) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(name, {}, function(fileEntry) {
          currentFile = fileEntry;
          fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
              updateVisualEditor(this.result);
            }
            reader.readAsText(file);
          }, fsError);
        }, fsError);
      };
```